# Floating images next to text with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm attempting a simple article-style floating images to the right of blocks of text -- but how do I make the paragraphs full length? Would prefer not complicating the HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/216n0gxs/

Current output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit         Sed do eiusmod             |-------|
amet, consectetur             tempor incididunt          |       |
adipiscing elit.              ut labore.                 |       |
                                                         |-------|
```

Desired output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. |-------|
                                                         |       |
Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.              |       |
                                                         |-------|
```

```css
article {
    display:flex;
}
article p {
}
img {
}
```

```html
<article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x350">
</article>
```

Comment: An image of the desired result would be helpful.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a wrapper around the text.

```css
article {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
div.text {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x350">
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (you need to add extra html markup to do the right way):

**CSS**

```
article {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.flex-item {
    -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
    flex: 1 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<article>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x350">
    </div>
</article>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/216n0gxs/2/)**